# Bugs after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If you take a look at the project here: http://www.leapfm.com/ you can scroll down and click More on the front page and it works. However, if you try doing that in New Songs tab it stays at 'Page is loading...'. I'm not quite sure why this is.

**new_songs.html.erb**

```
<div id="new_songs">
<%= render 'new_songs'%>
</div></div>
```

**_new_songs.html.erb (partial)**

```
<div id="layout-1">
<!--div class="left-side"> -->
<%#= will_paginate @songs %>
<h6>New songs</h6>
<hr>
<ol><% @songs.each do |song| %>
<span class="title">
<li><%= link_to song.title, song %><span class="subtext">  (<%= song.url %>)<br></li></span>


 <%#=link_to '&#9660'.html_safe, vote_against_song_path(song), :remote => true, :method => :put %> 

    posted <%= time_ago_in_words(song.created_at) + " ago" %>
    <small><span class="comments"></small> | <%= pluralize(song.comments.size, 'comment') %></span></small><br /></span>

<%#= link_to 'Show', song, class: "button small secondary" %>
<%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, song %>
<%= link_to('Destroy', song, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "button small secondary") if can? :destroy, song %>

<% end %>

</ol>
</div>
<div class="pagination-centered">
  <ul class="pagination">
<%#= will_paginate @songs %>
<!-- or custom pagination -->
<% if @songs.previous_page %>
  <%= link_to "Back", params.merge(page: @songs.previous_page) %>
<% end %>
<% if @songs.next_page %>
  <%= link_to "More", params.merge(page: @songs.next_page) %>
<% end %>
</ul></div>
```

**pagination.js**

```
$(function() {
  $(".pagination a").on("click", function() {
    $(".pagination").html("Page is loading...");
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

**song_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create ,:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]

  def extract_video

  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  @song.YouTubeAddy.extract_video_id

  end

  def vote_for
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      @song.plusminus = @song.votes_for
      @song.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_votes' }
      end
  end

  def vote_against
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_against(@song)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'update_votes' }
    end
  end

  def new_songs
    @songs = Song.order("id DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
  end


  # GET /Songs
  # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    if params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    else      
      @songs = Song.order('plusminus').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
  end

  # GET /Songs/1
  # GET /Songs/1.json
  def show
   @comment = Comment.new(song: @song) 
   @video_tag = YouTubeAddy.extract_video_id(@song.url)

  end

  # GET /Songs/new
  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  # GET /Songs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Songs
  # POST /Songs.json
  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.update(song_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # Song /Songs/1
  # Song /Songs/1.json
  def destroy
    @song.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_song
       @song = Song.find(params[:id])
     end

     def song_params
       params.require(:song).permit(:title, :artist, :url, :track, :user_id, :tag_list)
     end
  end
```

Comment: I don't see `page loading...`

Comment: Be sure you are here http://www.leapfm.com/new_songs scroll to the bottom and hit More. You'll be stuck on 'Page is loading...'

Comment: Where as the first page it works. Please see above code for troubleshooting.

Comment: Is the js on the New Song tab supposed to function like it does on the landing page? In any case, try to see if all your js got included.

Comment: Yes it's supposed to function the same as the landing. I think it has to do with the song_controller.rb. Specifically the new_songs action perhaps? I've added it above :)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34737/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18028703-bugs-after-deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are placing js code for 2 actions in the same file.

you have `index` action and `new_songs` action in `songs_controller.rb`, and you put your js in `index.js.erb`:

```
$("#songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("songs")) %>"); 
$("#new_songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("new_songs")) %>");
```

move the second line in a file called `new_songs.js.erb` and you are done.